# Cell returning sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to vba so bare with me. Currently I am trying to run a program on VBA to allow the cells in sheet 1 to be referenced to other sheets. E.G,

```
Alvin - sheet 2
Josh - sheet 3
```

And if the cell cannot be found it will be put as the file being worked on. VBA prompts me to write the macro name but I have named it yet it doesn't work

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code i am using and it doesn't work and prompts me to type out the macro name. Thank you for helping

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` is a reserved name for an event. You cannot rename it to `Worksheet_Change2`, then it does not work as event anymore.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ my bad it was my assumption that '''Worksheet_Change''' is the macro name

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and correct your code. Also add a question to your code because you didn't ask one yet. The `Worksheet_Change` event will run automatically when you change the content of cell A2 in that sheet. So you don't need to run that macro. Please clarify and write in your post what you expect your code to do and what it actually does. Because *"not working"* is a useless error description.

Comment: Standard is `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` and the code should be placed in the worksheet code, not in a module. How are you even calling this to get the naming error?

Comment: Also do not use `ActiveSheet` if you mean to refer to the sheet where the event is occurring: use `Me` instead.  There are cases where `Me` and `ActiveSheet` do not refer to the same sheet.